# What is YXEnternal64 in Win10? It's occupying a lot of CPU usage when bootup?

Tags: windows-10, cpu, cpu-usage

What is YXEnternal64? It's occupying a lot of CPU usage when bootup?

It's been almost happening for the last five bootups. Every time I can hear the CPU fan cooling  very loudly.
Sometimes it's also causing system hang ups.

Anyone having the same problem in Win10?

> Version 1803.17134.472

[image: 64]

Answer (score 0):

It is the "Rogue" software of "Ranger's Calendar". The CPU of this software is very high, and it is good to uninstall it.

Find the process in the task manager, right click to open the file location, and then uninstall it.

If you have "rogue" software on your computer, the following situations may occur:

1. When the user uses the computer to access the Internet, there will be a window that pops up continuously;
2. the computer browser was inexplicably modified to add a lot of work bars;
3. When a user opens a web page, the web page becomes a strange picture that is irrelevant.

Some "rogue software" is just for some purpose, such as advertising. Although these "rogue software" will not affect the normal use of the user's computer, when the user launches the browser, a web page will pop up to achieve the purpose of promotion.

Comment: Thanks. It’s a shady software from Youxia and had to delete it from PE.